# Trying to use ssh private key while using jmeter

Tags: linux, user-interface, jmeter, key, private

I am trying to connect to a remote host which require private key, how do I make jmeter to use this private key in order to connect?

what should I do exactly ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a public/private rsa key pair and save it on your server. Thus no password is required anymore.

If you are using Linux:

```
$ mkdir ~/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Now you need to generate a key: (makes a 4096 bit key)

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

This will look like: (just leave the passphrase blank)

```
$ Generating public/private rsa key pair.
$ Enter file in which to save the key (/home/<xxx>/.ssh/id_rsa):
$ Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
$ Enter same passphrase again:
$ Your identification has been saved in /home/<xxx>/.ssh/id_rsa.
$ Your public key has been saved in /home/<xxx>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

`Scp` the key on your server:

```
$ scp /home/<xxx>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <user>@<server_ip> <location_of_your_ssh_key_files>
```

`Ssh` to your server and add the key to your auth keys, backup them first:

```
$ cd <location_of_your_ssh_authkey_file>
$ cp authorized_keys authorized_keys_backup
$ cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

the usual location is:

```
/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa
```